# Unable to hit URL using GET method with params

Tags: reactjs

I have used react-router-dom with webpack and weppack-dev-server for development. My project is running, but when i directly hitting the url with paramameters in browser then it gives me
GET **http://localhost:8080/archives/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED** otherwise i hit the same url with Link component then it is running

```
//main.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, hashHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import Archives from './modules/Archives';
import Layout from './modules/Layout';
import Featured from './modules/Featured';
import Settings from './modules/Settings';
import Home from './modules/Home';
console.log('hi');

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <div>
        <Layout/>
        <Route exact path={'/'} component={Home}/>
        <Route path={'/featured'} component={Featured}/>
        <Route path={'/archives/:id'} component={Archives}/>
        <Route exact path={'/archives'} component={Archives}/>
        <Route path={'/settings'} component={Settings}/>
        </div>
    </Router>
    ),document.getElementById('app'));
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Layout.js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../css/main.css';
const bstyle = {
    color:'white',
    background: 333333,
    margin: '-9px',
};
export default class Layout extends React.Component{

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
      <h1>React Application</h1>
      <ul>
          <li><Link className='linktext' to='/'>Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link className='linktext' to='/archives'>Archives</Link></li>
          <li><Link className='linktext' to='/featured'>Featured</Link></li>
          <li><Link className='linktext' to='/settings'>Settings</Link></li>
      </ul>
      {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I see you using hashHistory, In this this case the URL, should be http://localhost:8080/#/archives/index.js

Comment: i Have used that url also but it gives me output flike localhost:8080 url. i want to run url with paramerters like localhost the route is defined for that which is /archived/:id id is parametet of that url..         Not working

Comment: why is index.js in url

Comment: i have used webpack-dev-server and i index.js in my webpack-config.js file `var config = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
       filename: './index.js',
       publicPath:''
    },
    module: {
       loaders: [
          {
             test: /\.js?$/,
             exclude: /node_modules/,
             loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react'
          },
          { 
              test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" 
        }
       ]
    },
    devServer: 
    {
         historyApiFallback: true
    }
 }
 module.exports = config;`

Comment: I have resolved the my problem. The problem is i have used latest version http-server when i minimize the version of http-server then project is working well(before i have used latest version is 0.10.0 and now i have using version 0.8.5)